# Google sheets splitting text to rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create an inventory system where I input the items of a drawer as a list separated by commas along with the drawer number and google sheets returns that list as separate cells, but with the same drawer number.
This is what I have
[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cFHY.png)
and [this is what I want it to return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D30EO.png), ideally on a separate sheet. I split the text into the rows using =transpose(SPLIT(Sheet1!C3, ",")), but what I'm stuck on is filling the column to the left (the drawer number A1, A2,...) I did it manually but it would be a pain to do so for all of the drawers. Is there any way to do this using a formula?
There won't be the same number of items in each drawer.

Here's my workbook if that's helpful.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ayXmwtJ1V4LB2ANgIYXscP-_KcuTWUTzMOHOYwPM_z0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Sheet1!C2:C="",,Sheet1!B2:B&"×"&SPLIT(Sheet1!C2:C, ","))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null")))
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible! Thank you